# Pygame problem : the collisions are weird

Tags: python, pygame

On my pygame I have a problem : the collisions are weird and they work half : on the border they work but on the midddle of the map no (sorry for the color) [were that work (yes) and were that not work (no)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CG8p.png)

[image]

here is the portion  of code for the deplacement :

```
    if game.pressed.get(pygame.K_d):
        if lvl.structure[game.player.rect.y // 64 + camY // 64][game.player.rect.x // 64 + 1 + camX // 64] is not 'T':
            game.player.move_right()
            #print(game.player.rect.x)
            if not screen_rect.contains(game.player.rect):
                game.player.rect.x -= HEIGHT -60 
                camX += -HEIGHT

    elif game.pressed.get(pygame.K_q):
        if lvl.structure[game.player.rect.y // 64 + camY // 64][game.player.rect.x // 64 + camX // 64] is not 'T':
            game.player.move_left()
            #print(game.player.rect.x)
            if not screen_rect.contains(game.player.rect):
                game.player.rect.x += HEIGHT - 60
                camX += HEIGHT

    elif game.pressed.get(pygame.K_s):
        print(game.player.rect.y)
        if lvl.structure[game.player.rect.y // 64 + 1 + camY // 64][game.player.rect.x // 64 + camX // 64] is not 'T':
            game.player.move_down()
            if not screen_rect.contains(game.player.rect):
                game.player.rect.y -= WIDHT - 80
                camY -= WIDHT

    elif game.pressed.get(pygame.K_z):
        if lvl.structure[game.player.rect.y // 64 + camY // 64][game.player.rect.x // 64 + camX // 64] is not 'T':
            game.player.move_up()
            #print(game.player.rect.y)
            if not screen_rect.contains(game.player.rect):
                game.player.rect.y += WIDHT - 80
                camY += WIDHT

    lvl.afficher(screen, 0, 0, camX, camY, game.player.rect.x, game.player.rect.y)
    screen.blit(game.player.image, game.player.rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

and for the level :

```
class Level(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.structure = 0
        self.map = []

    def generer(self):
        with open("niveau.txt", "r") as fichier:
            structure_niveau = []
            for ligne in fichier:
                ligne_niveau = []
                for sprite in ligne:
                    if sprite != '\n':
                        ligne_niveau.append(sprite)
                structure_niveau.append(ligne_niveau)
            self.structure = structure_niveau

    def afficher(self, fenetre, x, y, camX, camY, playerX, playerY):
        tailleSprite = 64
        self.collide = False
        #Camera.__init__(self, x, y)

        grass = pygame.image.load("assets/bloc/grass.png").convert_alpha()

        tree = pygame.image.load("assets/bloc/tree_grass.png").convert_alpha()

        no_texture = pygame.image.load("assets/bloc/no_texture.png").convert_alpha()

        num_ligne = 0
        for ligne in self.structure:
            num_case = 0
            for sprite in ligne:
                x = num_case * tailleSprite + camX
                y = num_ligne * tailleSprite + camY
                sprite_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 64, 64)
                screenRect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 1088, 836)
                aroundPlayer = pygame.Rect(playerX, playerY, 46, 64)
                if sprite == 'G':
                    if screenRect.contains(sprite_rect):
                        fenetre.blit(grass, (x, y))

                elif sprite == 'T':
                    if screenRect.contains(sprite_rect):
                        fenetre.blit(tree, (x, y))


                else:
                    if screenRect.contains(sprite_rect):
                        fenetre.blit(no_texture, (x, y))
                    #print(x, y)

                num_case += 1
            num_ligne += 1
```

Thank you in advance !!!!!

Comment: Do you really mean [`.contains()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.contains)? Do you not mean [`.colliderect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect)?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand

Comment: Try to use `.colliderect()` instead of `.contains()`. Everywhere.

Comment: On lvl.structure[game.player.rect.y // 64 + 1 + camY // 64][game.player.rect.x // 64 + camX // 64] is not 'T' ?

Comment: No. You should use the method `colliderect` instead of the method `contains`, everywhere in your code. (I count `contains` 7 times)

Comment: Ho thank you @Rabbid76 !! But that doesn't rule the problem of the tree on the image